# Separate Realm SWIFT data into lists -- and bring data back together?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So, I am a COMPLETE newbie, learning by doing real hands-on projects. I am attempting to create an app that can keep track of car parts. I'm trying to use Realm Database. In order to be organized, I'd like to keep everything separated by key bunches: "partInfo", "storeInfo", and "mechanicInfo" and then bring this back together again with the list feature of realm. Please see my code below and tell help me learn how to go about it? Thanks in advance!

I'm also trying to do MVC pattern--not sure if I did this right by separating everything out or not.

Here's my code for **storeinfo.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class StoreInfo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var storeName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var storeNumber: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var storeAddress: String = ""
    var catalog = LinkingObjects(fromType: Catalog.self, property: "stores")
    
    //var itemImgs = List<String>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
    }
}
```

Here's my code for **partinfo.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class PartInfo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var partName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var partNumber: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var partDescription: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var partCost: Double = 0.00
    @objc dynamic var partQuantity: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var purchaseDate: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var hasWarranty: Bool = true
    @objc dynamic var warrantyLength: String? = ""
    var catalog = LinkingObjects(fromType: Catalog.self, property: "parts")
    
    //var itemImgs = List<String>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
    }
}
```

here's my code for **mechanicinfo.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MechanicInfo: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var mechanicName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var mechanicNumber: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var mechanicAddress: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var mechanicCost: Double = 0.00
    @objc dynamic var serviceDate: String = ""
    var catalog = LinkingObjects(fromType: Catalog.self, property: "mechanics")
    
    
    //var itemImgs = List<String>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
    }
}
```

and finally (where I'm stuck at) -- the code for **Catalog.swift**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Catalog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    
    var parts = RealmSwift.List<PartInfo>()
    var stores = RealmSwift.List<StoreInfo>()
    var mechanics = RealmSwift.List<MechanicInfo>()
    
    
    //var itemImgs = List<String>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
    }
```

when I go to try to use it, I'm getting an error of already using the same name. can't use it twice: (so I had to do 3 instances of wipers, which works, but it's not what I wanted...please help!)

My **ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

        let wipers = PartInfo()
        
        wipers.partName = "TRICO HD 32 Inch Wiper Blades"
        wipers.partNumber = "67-324"
        wipers.hasWarranty = true
        wipers.warrantyLength = "2 years"
        wipers.purchaseDate = "04/21/2021"
        wipers.partCost = 34.99
        wipers.partQuantity = 2
        wipers.partDescription = "Great set. Lifespan of 6 - 9 months."
        
        let wipers2 = StoreInfo()
        
        wipers2.storeName = "O'Reilly AutoParts"
        wipers2.storeAddress = "1003 W Broad St, Groveland, FL 34736"
        wipers2.storeNumber = "4474"
        
        let wipers3 = MechanicInfo()
        
        wipers3.serviceDate = "04/24/2021"
        wipers3.mechanicAddress = "17605 Sunshine Circle, Winter Garden, FL, 34787"
        wipers3.mechanicCost = 289.58
        wipers3.mechanicName = "Bob Barnicles"
        wipers3.mechanicNumber = "353-256-7893"
        
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(wipers)
            realm.add(wipers2)
            realm.add(wipers3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "when I go to try to use it" <-- You did not show how you "try to use" `Catalog` at all. And what is the error message?

Comment: Add `var partInfo: Results<PartInfo>!` or something before `viewDidLoad`.  And set `realm` to `partInfo` or whatever in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Sweeper I am trying to get all the information from the 3 sections - Partinfo, Storeinfo and mechanic info to be stored TOGETHER, under the same one variable, instead of having to do wipers1 2 and 3. I want to call catalog and put the information into just that.

Comment: @ElTomato Can you explain what that does? I'm sorry, I'm really new to all this, and I don't quite understand.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering, should I have a unique id for all three sections, or should I just have one id on the catalog? I need to know the best way to go about this. Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Your goal is a bit vague. You're text says *bring them back together again*. Then your comment says *stored TOGETHER, under the same one variable*. Nobody knows the scope of your project or how the objects relate. *Why* do you need a catalog object? Are you storing multiple catalogs? Providing us a clear description of what you're trying to do an how the objects relate will help us to help you. Also, telling us what queries you want to run will help us understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Jay - Ok. To clarify: I'd like to store information about different car parts in 1 catalog. all of that information being broken down into 3 sections- partinfo, storeinfo, & mechnic info. Currently, each of these are separated out into different classes & realm objects (if I did that right) What I want to know is how do I pull up the information under just ONE object--catalog? I have them linked to catalog via Realm's list feature. Is this the approriate way to do it? If so, I'd like to know how to put all this information into one variable, not part1, part2, and part3. Does this make sense?

Comment: Kind of like a CRM having different sections of information about a customer, such as their 'personal information', 'payment information', 'profile/social media account', 'contact information', etc, but all the elements makes up the ONE user profile, its just broken down into manageable chunks. i Hope this makes more sense

Comment: If you are never going to have any more than one catalog and it in itself, has no additional functionality, then it has no purpose. Your second comment is different because having only one catalog is very different than a CRM you describe because it has *multiple* customers. e.g. you won't ever query across customers (catalogs) because there's only one. Maybe if you can define what this catalog object does or why you think it's needed, it would make the question clearer.

Comment: @Jay oh...I thought it'd be similar because I'm having _multiple parts_ each with different information...? So should I get rid of the 3 parts and just keep everything in one object?

Comment: No way for us to know as it's not clear (as mentioned above) from the question what you're doing with these objects or what their relationship is. In other words a Catalog could have Parts but a Catalog won't have a Mechanic (or maybe it will, see?). Or is a Mechanic related to a Catalog in some way? What kind of information will you be querying? We need to understand that to help. Keep in mind when asking questions they need to be brief and specific - take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jay ok. So, yes, I'd like all parts of catalog to be searchable. I plan to query based off things like the purchase date/ service date/ and part name / item number. But ideally anything they put in, shoud be searchable. The 'Home Screen' will consist of a page that just says 'view all parts', 'add new part', 'search for a part'. And those will be the other screens. Every catalog will contain all 3 sections. Does this clarify? And THANK YOU for working with me/being patient. I'm sorry. 

Comment: By your description, no 'Catalog' needed. You already have a Parts Object so that would be addable and searchable by any of the part properties. It's not clear how a Mechanic or Store is related. I suggest sitting down with pen and paper and draw a diagram as to how those three things relate - and - what you want to display to your end user. As it is, the Store and Mechanic have no connection to anything (so far) so removing them would have no impact on your app since it's a 'parts app'. (hint: YOU need to figure that out).

Comment: @Jay Got it. Thank you so much for the help & your patience!